# Go test <function> returns undefined: <function>

Tags: go, testing

Trying to run "go test sum_test.go" returns an error:

./sum_test.go:18:13: undefined: SumInt8
FAIL    command-line-arguments [build failed]

I'm taking an introductory course in golang. Our teacher distributed a code-file, sum.go, and a testing-file, sum_test.go. Trying to run "go test" on sum_test.go returns the error above. The code runs fine on our teachers mac, and he's having difficulties recreating the problem. Here's my go environment settings: https://pastebin.com/HcuNVcAF

sum.go

```
package sum

func SumInt8(a, b int8) int8 {
  return a + b
}

func SumFloat64(a, b float64) float64 {
  return a + b
}
```

sum_test.go

```
package sum

import "testing"

// Check https://golang.org/ref/spec#Numeric_types and stress the limits!
var sum_tests_int8 = []struct{
  n1       int8
  n2       int8
  expected int8
}{
  {1, 2, 3},
  {4, 5, 9},
  {120, 1, 121},
}

func TestSumInt8(t *testing.T) {
for _, v := range sum_tests_int8 {
    if val := SumInt8(v.n1, v.n2); val != v.expected {
        t.Errorf("Sum(%d, %d) returned %d, expected %d", 
v.n1, v.n2, val, v.expected)
    }
  }
}
```

I see no particular errors, so I expected "go test sum_test.go" to run, and succeed. However it seems it can't find the method SumInt8 in sum.go.

Comment: The arguments to `go test` are *packages*, not *files*. This is the same as for the build and install commands. Try `go test .` or simply `go test` (or, if you really want to, list *all* files required to build the tests).

Answer (score 27, accepted):

> ```
> $ go help packages
> ```
>
> Many commands apply to a set of packages:
>
> ```
> go action [packages]
> ```
>
> Usually, [packages] is a list of import paths.
>
> An import path that is a rooted path or that begins with a . or ..
>   element is interpreted as a file system path and denotes the package
>   in that directory.
>
> Otherwise, the import path P denotes the package found in the
>   directory DIR/src/P for some DIR listed in the GOPATH environment
>   variable (For more details see: 'go help gopath').
>
> If no import paths are given, the action applies to the package in the
>   current directory.
>
> As a special case, if the package list is a list of .go files from a
>   single directory, the command is applied to a single synthesized
>   package made up of exactly those files, ignoring any build constraints
>   in those files and ignoring any other files in the directory.

---

List all the files in the current directory used in the test:

```
go test sum_test.go sum.go
```

or simply test the complete package in the current directory.

```
go test
```

---

For example,

```
$ go test -v sum_test.go sum.go
=== RUN   TestSumInt8
--- PASS: TestSumInt8 (0.00s)
PASS
ok      command-line-arguments  0.002s
$
```

or, for the complete package

```
$ go test -v
=== RUN   TestSumInt8
--- PASS: TestSumInt8 (0.00s)
PASS
ok      so/sum  0.002s
$
```

Option '-v' produces verbose output.

`sum_test.go`:

```
package sum

import "testing"

// Check https://golang.org/ref/spec#Numeric_types and stress the limits!
var sum_tests_int8 = []struct {
    n1       int8
    n2       int8
    expected int8
}{
    {1, 2, 3},
    {4, 5, 9},
    {120, 1, 121},
}

func TestSumInt8(t *testing.T) {
    for _, v := range sum_tests_int8 {
        if val := SumInt8(v.n1, v.n2); val != v.expected {
            t.Errorf("Sum(%d, %d) returned %d, expected %d",
                v.n1, v.n2, val, v.expected)
        }
    }
}
```

`sum.go`:

```
package sum

func SumInt8(a, b int8) int8 {
    return a + b
}

func SumFloat64(a, b float64) float64 {
    return a + b
}
```

---